# Adding a preprocessor language to the style portion of a vueify component causes build to fail without error

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, vue.js

I'm experimenting with the [vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify) transformer. I have a test component called scoreboard:

```
<style>
.scorecard-panel{
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: #fbd900;

}
table{
    width: 300px;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
th,td{
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
th{
    background-color:rgb(0, 10, 255);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<template>
    <div class="scorecard-panel">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Chris
                </th>
                <th>
                    Ruthie
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <counter></counter>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <counter></counter>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
var counter = require('./counter.vue');

module.exports = {

    data: function (){
        return {
            test: 'worked'
        }
    },
    components:{
        counter: counter
    }
}
</script>
```

Everything works when the component is defined as above, but when I try to add the preprocessor language 'sass' to the style section:

```
<style lang="sass">
.scorecard-panel{
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: #fbd900;

}
...
```

My gulp build processes fails without error:

[image: Example of build failing]

Here's my gulp file for reference:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var vueify = require('vueify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

gulp.task('build-app', function (){
    console.log('Building App...');
    return browserify('src/js/app.js')
        .transform(vueify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function (){
    gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.{js,vue}', ['build-app']);
});
```

Since I'm new to vueify (and vue really) I'm sure there's something that I'm doing wrong or missing that is causing this error. Does anyone see the hangup?

I should also note that I know the style rules in my example don't need a sass preprocessor as currently defined; I removed the nesting of the rules so that I could verify that it was the language preprocessor causing the error and not the rules' syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the `node-sass` npm package installed?

try `npm install node-sass` then run it again.  Although I don't know `DependableChangeClientV3` means.

Comment: Ah, that's definitely a facepalm moment. No, I hadn't installed the node-sass package. I missed [the section in the readme where it tells you the specific preprocessor packages necessary](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify#enabling-pre-processors). I installed node-sass and that fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh and DependableChangeClientV3 is just the name of the directory the prototype I'm building is in.